# One to many relationship: Couldn't find Ofertum with 'id'=3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, routes, one-to-many

I have problem to link to show file 
http://localhost:3000/sigs/3 
I got this error
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SigsController#show
Couldn't find Ofertum with 'id'=3

Please help me. Here is my codes 
I have two models: One for offers and one for signs
Each offer have signs and each sign have one offer

In sig model

```
  belongs_to :ofertum
```

in ofertum model

```
  has_many :sigs
```

in routes

```
  resources :oferta
  resources :sigs
```

in sigs controller

```
class SigsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @ofertum = Ofertum.find(params[:id])
    @sig = @ofertum.sigs.build
  end
  def create
    @ofertum = Ofertum.find(params[:id])
    @sig = @ofertum.sigs.build(sig_params)
    if @sig.save
      redirect_to sigs_path(:id => @ofertum.id)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @ofertum = Ofertum.find(params[:id])
    @sigs=@ofertum.sigs
    if @sigs.destroy
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
  def show
    @ofertum = Ofertum.find(params[:id])
    @sigs=@ofertum.sigs
  end


  def edit
  end

  def update
  end
  def index
  end

  def destroy
  end
   private
  def sig_params
    sig_params = params.require(:sig).permit([:name,:comment,:description,:price,:image])
  end
end
```

In oferta index.html.erb

```
<% @oferta.each do |o| %>
    <ul class="cat">
      <li class="pull-left"><h2><%= link_to o.offer,o %></h2><br><h4><%= o.description %></h4>
        <div class="main">
          <% if o.sigs.exists? %>
            <div id="myBtnContainer">
              <% for item in o.sigs %>
                <button class="btn active"  onclick="filterSelection('<%= item.name %>')"><%=  item.name%><%= link_to item.description,item  %><br></button>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

              <% for item in o.sigs %>
                <div class="column <%= item.name %>">
                  <div class="content">
                    <%= image_tag item.image.url(), style: "width:100%"%>
                    <h4><br><%= item.name %></h4>
                    <p><%= item.comment %></p>    
                  </div>
                </div>
              <% end %><br><br>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

In the database

```
class AddNameToSig < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
    add_column :sigs, :name, :string
    add_column :sigs, :comment, :string
    add_column :sigs, :description, :text
    add_column :sigs, :price, :string
  end
end
```

in sigs show.html.erb

```
<%= @sig.name %>
<div class="container">
<%= link_to  @sig, class: "btn tf-btn btn-default", method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this sign?" } do %>Delete <% end %> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The param in the path `/sigs/3` is about a sig, not an ofertum. So you might do this way

```
def show
  sig = Sig.find(params[:id])
  @sigs = sig.ofertum.sigs
end
```

or

```
def show
  ofertum = Sig.find(params[:id]).ofertum
  @sigs = ofertum.sigs
end
```

and yes, if you need even the ofertum in the view

```
def show
  @ofertum = Sig.find(params[:id]).ofertum
  @sigs = @ofertum.sigs
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want  in the show page to see the sign name, price, description

Comment: So? Do it. What's the problem?

Comment: undefined method `price' for #<Sig::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007fc12382a820>

Comment: What's the sig you want display field of? The one for the params? Then just add `@sig = Sign.find(params[:id])` and use that `@sig`

Comment: Thank you so much that solve the show problem. But can you help me in the delete and edit controller

Comment: Open another question please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57244487/ror-one-to-many-relationship-how-to-edit-update-and-delete-each-column-inside-th